# Can I put my Google App Engine app (*.appspot.com) on a VPN or behind a firewall?

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, vpn

I want to set something up so only authorized users (perhaps on a VPN) can see my Google App Engine app. Is this possible?

EDIT: I want to make a private dev version of the app (different app engine app). And I want to make a private "dev console" that can be used to simulate usage by calling endpoints with task queues. I will still have authentication, and I thought it would make sense to have this dev environment hidden from the rest of the world. Unnecessary?

Comment: Are you using any authentication? If so -  why isn't that enough? If your VPN's IP address is static you could simply make your web-framework only respond to the requests that are coming from that IP address and ignore the rest.

Comment: The usual way of handling this would be to limit access to the Application to users of your Google Apps domain, and simply requiring Login on all your endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I updated my question clarifying my end goal.

Comment: probably unnecessary. If you don't want to go to the extra work of putting up a 'nothing to see here' home page, picking a long, obscure app id is what I've seen people do.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do for test environments is to put this in your web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin required</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This makes sure you have to be logged in as an admin to view the site. You can add users to your project in the permissions screen:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/[YOURPROJECT]/permissions

Answer (score 0):

An easy way doing what you want is to deploy a "dev" version to AppEngine, then you can access it with this URI : `http://dev.app_name.appspot.com`.

The default version still accessible. And you can test your endpoints with the dev URL.

For OAuth2, don't forget to add the dev url in the OAuth API Console.